# Amsart with algorithm2e introduces extraneous text into pdf file with Texlive 2011

Tags: incompatibility, algorithm2e, amsart

I just removed the default Ubuntu TexLive 2009 installation and installed TexLive 2011 using `install-tl`. However, now I am facing problems with the `amsart` and `algorithm2e` packages. Specifically, when I compile a file with
the following text:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document} 
   This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

rather than

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document} 
   This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

then the PDF output produced by `pdflatex` (or the `dvi` output produced by `latex`) contains the following text on the first page (and half of the first page disappears: it is as if this text pushes everything on the first page down).

> La-TeX Error:Missing document See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for >explanation.You’re in trouble here. Try typing ¡re-turn¿  to proceed.If
>   that doesn’t work, type X ¡return¿ to quit.1111111

This text disappears if I use the `article` style instead, or if I remove the `algorithm2e` package with `amsart`.  Notice that this text *does not*
appear as a console error message: the compilation shows no errors. This actually occurs at the top of the first page of the output `pdf` (or `dvi`) file. In fact, although I put the message in a more human readable form above, it actually contains several line breaks in between words; in particular, almost all the hyphens in the output above are followed by a line break.

Is this a documented problem with TexLive? What could be the reasons for this happening? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any .aux files from a previous run? Try deleting those and rerunning.

Comment: Hi Peter Grill, Thanks for your advice. I had tried deleting the aux files before, and that does not work.  However, in trying to create an MWE, I think I isolated the cause of the problem.  The Text I quoted above appears only when I use the algorithm2e package.  I am editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: Great. Often problems can be solved as you create a MWE.  Remove all the code you can which still exhibits the problem and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I added the minimal amount of code with which I can produce the error to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried your `amsart` version and it compiles for me.  Are you perhaps also loading `natbib` (as that has to be loaded before the `algorithm2e` package).

Comment: No I am not loading natbib.  I compiled a file with exactly the text in my `amsart` example.  It compiled without error, *but* the PDF output contained an error message. The `article` example, or the `amsart` example with the `algorithm2e` package removed produces correct output.  Also, I thing I did not emphasize enough that this problem was not present in Texlive 2009 (which ships with Ubuntu) and it occurred only when I shifted to Texlive 2011.

Comment: "...`amsart` example with the `algorithm2e`..." in my post above should be "...`amsart` example without the `algorithm2e`..."

Comment: Yes, BOTH your examples compile fine for me. But, I am not on Ubuntu.

Comment: This problem is not just specific to Ubuntu, nor using the `twoside` documentclass option; similar problem on Windows for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), from `v4.00` started using the [`relsize` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) to scale the size of the algorithm line numbers. However, this clashes with some document class, as stated in the release notes for `algorithm2e`:

> **OPTION `norelsize`**: Starting from this release (`v4.00`),
>   `algorithm2e` package uses `relsize` package in order to get relative
>   size for lines numbers; but it seems that some rare classes (such as
>   `inform1.cls`) are not compatible with `relsize`; to have
>   `algorithm2e` working, this option makes `algorithm2e` not to load
>   `relsize` package and go back to previous definition by using
>   `\scriptsize` font for lines numbers.

This seems to also clash with `amsart`. However, this is fixed using the above package option:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage[norelsize]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document} 
   This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner. I actually changed my algorithm code (There was not much of it) to algorithmicx (which is apparently newer) and it compiled.  I hope your reply  would be useful for others though (searching for "algorithm2e and amsart" on Google brings this reply up as the first link :).

Answer (score 0):

When using `TexLive` 2011 (on the arXiv)
with `amsart`, I had the same error message:

`LaTeX Error: Missing document See the La- TeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.You’re in trouble here. Try typing return to pro- ceed.If that doesn’t work, type X return to quit.`

and half of the first page disappeared.

Removing the line

`\usepackage{relsize}`

solved the problem.

(The problem didn't show up with `TexLive` 2009, and has been fixed with `TexLive` 2013.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format