# Mac vs Ubuntu LaTeX error

Tags: errors, compiling

I'm getting a very strange error.

I have a LaTeX document that I compile with a Makefile (below), when I compile it on my Ubuntu machine everything is fine, but when I compile it on my mac the first page of my pdf displays an error, the second page is the title page and the rest compiled just fine.

The error on the first page I get is:

```
Latex error: missing document see the latex manual or latex
companion for explanation.
You're in trouble here. Try typing 'return' to proceed. 
if that doesn't work type X return to quit.1111111
```

Any ideas what is going on?

My Makefile executes `latex`; `bibtex`; `latex`; `latex`; `dvips`; `ps2pdf`;

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'd love to, but I have no idea where the error is coming from. I figured maybe someone had a similar problem in the past and could give me a hint where to look.

Comment: LaTeX documents are indented from OS. Maybe you have different TeX Live/MacTeX versions.

Comment: Ah, that could be it! I searched the error online and it seems some kind of mismatch between versions.

Comment: @janjust Follow the MWE link Marco provided, it provides help on how to find out where the error comes from. It does sound like an encoding error, or, to be precise, perhaps something about line-ending characters. Fortunately, Windows, Linux and Mac OS all use different things there ...

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/amsart-with-algorithm2e-introduces-extraneous-text-into-pdf-file-with-texlive-20) is someone who had the same problem. I'll look here see if I can find the culprit.

Comment: I meant "independent"

Comment: Yeah so according the the link I provided this has something to do with some old .cls files incompatibility with relsize, which some packages use, and hence the error. Now just to find the package that is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok to answer my own question. Although this may be redundant because the description [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/amsart-with-algorithm2e-introduces-extraneous-text-into-pdf-file-with-texlive-20) answers it. The culprit was `\usepackage{relsize}` which is not supported by some `.cls` files. Moreover, packages that use `relsize` will also be affected.