# Rescaling a math symbol?

Tags: scaling

I am trying to rescale a math symbol while using the `amsbook` package. At first I was using the `relsize` package, but it creates clashes with the AMS packages: [Amsart with algorithm2e introduces extraneous text into pdf file with Texlive 2011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/amsart-with-algorithm2e-introduces-extraneous-text-into-pdf-file-with-texlive-20/30990#30990).

Then, I read here [Change font size relative to current font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56676/change-font-size-relative-to-current-font-size) that the `amsbook` has a similar option. I looked it up, and there is the `\larger` command. But it doesn't work. I used:

```
  \newcommand{\Alpha}{\larger{\alpha}}
```

and the `\alpha` does not change in size.

Any ideas how to rescale the `\alpha` so that it is relatively larger (I used to use `mathlarger` from `relsize` which worked fine, but created clashes with AMS packages, as I said)?

Comment: Do you need the symbol also in subscripts/superscripts?

Comment: @egreg, not really, no. it would be nice to have the option, but I can go without it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The AMS classes have a `\larger` command that works out of the box:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\Alpha}{\mbox{\larger$\alpha$}}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\Alpha$

\Large
$\alpha\Alpha$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This won't work in subscripts/superscripts, though. Unfortunately `\text` doesn't update `\@currsizeindex`, so using `\text` instead of `\mbox`, which would be the obvious attempt, doesn't give the desired result.

A possible way out is to update the sizes manually:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\newcommand{\Alpha}{\mbox{\larger$\alpha$}}

\newcommand{\Alpha}{\mathchoice
  {\mbox{\larger$\alpha$}}
  {\mbox{\larger$\alpha$}}
  {\mbox{\larger[-2]$\alpha$}}
  {\mbox{\larger[-4]$\alpha$}}
}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\Alpha_{\alpha\Alpha_{\alpha\Alpha}}$

\Large
$\alpha\Alpha_{\alpha\Alpha_{\alpha\Alpha}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve arbitrary scaling with the `scalerel` package.  I demonstrate here with `\Alpha` as 1.5 times the original. (Note: in this case, `\scaleobj` is functionally equivalent to a `\scalebox` that defaults to math mode).

It also automatically obeys the current math style, as shown in the second line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2016/12/29]
\newcommand\Alpha{\scaleobj{1.5}{\alpha}}
\begin{document}
\( \alpha\Alpha \)

\(\Alpha^{\Alpha^{\Alpha}}\) versus
\(\alpha^{\alpha^{\alpha}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2016/12/29]
\newcommand{\B}[2]{\scaleobj{#2}{#1}}
\begin{document}
    $\B{\alpha}{2.5}\alpha\B{\beta}{5}$
\end{document}
```

You have this result:

[image]

The code define a new command with 2 mandatory argument:

#1 the character to scale,

#2 the scale factor