# Scaling up a math symbol messes up toc

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, sectioning, scaling

I am trying to scale up a greek letter inside a math formula. To do this, i follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112759/300361) and use `\scaleobj` from the package `scalerel`

However, when I try to use an expression that includes my upscaled symbol in a section heading and use `\tableofcontents`, errors occur.

What is the reason for the errors? How can I use my little formula in a section heading without breaking my table of contents?

Here is a mimium error producing example:

```
% minimum working example to demonstrate a problem with math mode and scalebox not working together with headers and table of contents
% this is the base class of my document
\documentclass{scrbook}
% minimum number of imports
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% define upscaled \pi
\newcommand{\PI}{\scaleobj{1.5}{\pi}}
% use this symbol inside math mode
\newcommand{\mypi}{\(\PI_\text{mypi}\)}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Main Chapter}

Some text about \mypi.

% comment out the following line to get a minimum working example
\section{What's the matter with \mypi?}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: your definition is not robust, and such commands can break when wandering through files to another location (the toc in your case). Either protect when using it: `\protect\mypi`, or define it in a robust way e.g. with `\NewDocumentCommand{\mypi}{}{\(\PI_\text{mypi}\)}`

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem :)

Comment: Unrelated please don't use `\text` to write something upright. Thst is not what that macro does use `\textrm` or `\mathrm`. Why? The output from `\text` depends on context, thus sometimes it is upright, other times italic or sans serif. Not what you want