# Trouble submitting paper to arXiv - amsart issues?

Tags: algorithm2e, amsart, arxiv

I just attempted to submit a paper to the arXiv.  Unfortunately, they would not accept a .pdf and insisted on the LaTeX source code.  I uploaded the LaTeX source code along with three figures in .pdf format (that may be part of the problem: see below).  When I clicked on the "view paper" button, the first page had a message like this:

> "La- TeX Er- ror: Miss- ing doc- u- mentSee the La- TeX man- ual or La- TeX Com- pan- ion for ex- pla- na- tion.You’re in trou- ble here. Try typ- ing ¡re- turn¿ to pro- ceed.If that doesn’t work, type X ¡re- turn¿ to quit.1111111".

That message was squeezed into the left part of the page.  Everything after that looked fine.

I couldn't find a solution for my problem in the arXiv's FAQ's, so I e-mailed them.  They promptly replied that:

"The first page of the PDF is a common error. Please note arXiv is a fully automated electronic repository. For more information on the issue please see:

[Amsart with algorithm2e introduces extraneous text into pdf file with Texlive 2011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/amsart-with-algorithm2e-introduces-extraneous-text-into-pdf-file-with-texlive-20)  "

I did read that link.  However, I'm not sure it addresses my problem, for several reasons.  First, the paper compiles fine on my own computer (using MikTeX, TexNicCenter, and Windows).  Second, I am not using "algorithm2e" at all, at least not knowingly.  Third, that Stack Exchange post is over two years old.  I installed brand new versions of MikTeX and TexNicCenter today.

EDIT:  I created a mini-version of my file that works fine on my own computer:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,comment,mathrsfs,times,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%
\begin{document}
 Let $\theta \in (0,1]$ and
$\alpha \in [\theta^2/2,\theta)$.  Let $P$ and $S$ be points on $S$ separated by arc length $\theta$.  Let $Q$ and $R$ lie on the arc
$\stackrel{\textstyle\frown}{PS}$,
with
$\stackrel{\textstyle\frown}{QR}$ having arc length $\alpha$,
$\stackrel{\textstyle\frown}{PQ}$ and
$\stackrel{\textstyle\frown}{RS}$
having equal arc length, and $Q$ between $P$ and $R$.  Let $T$ and $U$ lie on the chord
${\overline {PS}}$, chosen such that $\triangle PQT$ and $\triangle RSU$ are right triangles.  Then $\triangle PQT$ and $\triangle RSU$ have disjoint closures.
%
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine on my own computer.  I had used `\usepackage{arcs}`, but a commenter pointed out that my arc-like commands did not require the `arcs` package at all, and I have heard that package is bugged, so I will remove `\userpackage{arcs}`.  Another commenter suggested that I needed to include a line that forces the .pdf images to be handled correctly (I don't remember the comment exactly, and I can't see it and type this answer at the same time).  I will include that line.

FINAL EDIT: I followed the advice of several commenters below and it seems to have worked.  I submitted the paper and it looked fine when I previewed it, so I submitted it.

Comment: Please, post a full [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can determine the problem and provide you a solution.

Comment: Did you look at http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#pdflatex ?

Comment: The `arcs` package is loading `relsize`, so it is the same sort of problem as the linked question, but the solution is not so clear.  Please update your code to provide a complete document to demonstrate how you use the commands from that package.

Comment: bogus: I don't see what is not clear. You have a code that doesn't compile on arXiv. Shorten this code as much as possible so that it still doesn't work on arXiv, and you get a MWE. What is unclear about it, please?

Comment: The problem appears when you first compile the file or only when you finally sumbit it? I thought it appears at the first compile, which is a phase that does not disturb anyone at arXiv...

Comment: Well, then you should know that until you hit the very final "Sumbit" button, you can do whatever you want, and nobody gets notified about your paper ;)

Comment: @tohecz : that is essential information.  I did not know I could "test" my paper in the arXiv without actually submitting it.

Comment: If you have figures in PDF format, you have to force arXiv to use `pdflatex` to compile your file. You can do this by putting `\pdfoutput=1` in the first line. Otherwise arXiv tries to use the regular `latex` which does not support PDF figures.

Comment: The `arcs` package has a really bad bug that causes LaTeX to hang with recent distributions.

Comment: @bogus Your example has no `arcs` command. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15473/4427

Comment: Does the new file give the same arxiv error?

Comment: The first line of the document.

Comment: Best to put `\pdfoutput=1` before `\documentclass` as the first noncomment line in the file.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : no, I think everything is fixed.  I'll edit my question in a moment to report this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, arXiv tries to compile your document using the regular `latex` command, which does not support PDF figures. To override this behavior, you can put `\pdfoutput=1` as the first line of your main *.tex file. This forces arXiv to use `pdflatex` to compile your document. Note that in such case your paper will be available only in PDF format (there will be no PostScript version).

An alternative solution is to provide all figures in EPS format. Then arXiv will first use the regular `latex` to produce a PostScript version of your paper, and then convert it to PDF.

I usually go for only the PDF version for several reasons:

- it is often a pain to produce pictures in EPS format (you might get some undesirable artifacts or loose transparency effects);
- the regular `latex` does not know how to break long URLs (which might make your references look ugly), whereas `pdflatex` has no problem with it;
- I don't use the PS format myself and I don't know anyone who would use it on a regular basis, so there is very little benefit of having it.

However, for some reason many journals still require you to submit pictures in EPS format (even though they produce a PDF file in the end), so you might eventually still need to do it.

Comment: @Maris Ozols : Thank you for your informative answer (as well as fixing my problem).  Do you have any idea why so many people use PostScript and journals require EPS files?  Is it for historical reasons (does PostScript predate the extremely popular .pdf format?)   I know it is possible to program in PostScript but I doubt that many people actually do.

Comment: Actually, it is a question that I would also like to know an answer to. It definitely has a historic component to it. When I was an undergrad 10 years ago, I compiled my thesis to DVI (device independent) format and then generated either PS or PDF file from it (indeed, this is what arXiv does by default too). However, these days we have pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX that directly generate PDF, and we have TeXworks editor that has integrated PDF preview. Because of this PostScript seems obsolete to me. Maybe people who are more in publishing have more clue why it is still used.

Comment: Btw, I knew how to fix your problem because I had the exact same frustrating experience myself when I was trying to upload my first paper on arXiv. ;) It was back in 2008.